# Do variables sent using POST get sent to PHP if using mod_rewrite?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

How do sites such as Stack Overflow submit forms using `action="/questions/ask/submit"`?

I would've thought `mod_rewrite` would lose the `$_POST` vars?

**.htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L]
```

**index.php**

```
$q = explode("/", $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
if($q[1]!=""){
  switch($q[1]){
    case "test":
      include("test.php");
      break;
      ...
```

**test.php**

```
<?php
  if(isset($_POST["submitButton"])){
    echo "Submitted";
  }
  else{
    echo "Not submitted";
  }
?>
<form method="post" action="/test/submit">
  <input type="submit" name="submitButton">
</form>
```

**If I remove** `action="/test/submit"`

If my URL is `/test` then it returns `Not submitted` when I click the button.
If my URL is `/test.php` then it returns `Submitted` when I click the button.

---

## Update

For the time being, I'm using the following.

**index.php**

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
  $q = explode("/", $_POST["url"]);
}
else{
  $q = explode("/", $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
}
...
```

**test.php**

```
<form method="post" action="/">
  <input type="hidden" name="url" value="/test">
  ...
```

This allows my test.php to receive the post vars.

If there are no errors by the user, I use `header("Location: test/success");`

If there are errors, the URL will have to be `/` which isn't ideal.

## Update/resolution

The problem may be with Apache 2.4. The fix was to add this line to index.php:

```
parse_str(file_get_contents("php://input"),$_POST);
```

With this method, there's no need for any `action="..."` (this will successfully POST to itself, even if the URL is a slug).

Comment: Just try it yourself and find out.

Comment: I have. `mod_rewrite` loses the `$_POST` vars.

Comment: POST variables are carried over on internal redirects, but not 301s etc. However, I'm fairly sure you could do that if required.

Comment: Are you doing a R=301 or something similar?

Comment: Strange. I redirect all my URLs and POST is always carried across. My guess would be an issue in your PHP, otherwise in your Apache.

Comment: @rybo111 Try posting your PHP and the opening `<form>` tag as well. The best questions include as much relevant code as possible for people to try to work out what's going on.

Comment: @KohjahBreese would you mind sharing your rewrite rules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mod_rewrite does not affect post variables.

Comment: my bad, but who's using this modifier today if we are talking about rewriting to the index.php?

Comment: Touche. It's not in his mod_rewrite.

Comment: This must be correct because it works perfectly fine on another server, so I've tagged it as correct.

Comment: Turns out I needed `parse_str(file_get_contents("php://input"),$_POST);` in index.php

Answer (score 3):

`/questions/ask/submit` is probably controlled by a CMS. meaning most requests are redirected to a single file, which then interprets them. This redirect is done with mod_rewrite usually, as your question indicates. mod_rewrite accepts a number of 'switches' to tell it what to do. That being said, there is no known bug with mod_rewrite 'messing up' `$_POST` data. Apache is what passes this data to PHP. mod_rewrite passes that to Apache. If your `$_POST` data gets messed up, you have a bad rule some where.

Here is an example of how a common CMS, WordPress, directs all traffic, regardless of method, to a central controller, which then interprets the untarnished `$_POST` data:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L] 
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
  RewriteRule . /index.php [L] 
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

TOP DOWN EXPLANATION:

- only execute this if the mod_rewrite module is active
- turn on the rewrite engine, so that it accepts your new rules
- make all your rewrites, rewrite to the document root `/`
- if the request was directly to `index.php` then force mod_rewrite to not process more rules and load index.php
- if the requested url does not directly map to a file
- AND if the requested url does not direclty map to a directory
- send all data, including requested url, _GET, _POST, etc, to index.php, and dont process any other rules

**EDIT (after sample files were submitted in question)**

Here are my complete files. With these exact files, on a Apache 2.2 and PHP 5.4 install, this works perfectly.

**.htaccess**

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

**index.php**

```
<?php
$q = explode("/", $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
if($q[1]!=""){
  switch($q[1]){
    case "test":
      include("test.php");
    break;
  }   
}
```

**test.php**

```
<?php
  if(isset($_POST["submitButton"])){
    echo "Submitted";
  }else{
    echo "Not submitted";
  }
?>
<form method="post" action="/test/submit">
  <input type="submit" name="submitButton">
</form>
```

**directory list, so you can compare permissions**

NOTE: *apache runs as nobody.nobody on my test machine*

```
drwxrwxr-x 2 nobody git 4096 Dec 22 03:34 ./
drwxrwxr-x 3 nobody git 4096 Dec 22 03:26 ../
-rw-rw-r-- 1 nobody git  244 Dec 22 03:29 .htaccess
-rw-rw-r-- 1 nobody git  134 Dec 22 03:27 index.php
-rw-rw-r-- 1 nobody git  194 Dec 22 03:28 test.php
```

If this does not work for you, you probably have a permission problem. This exact code works.

Comment: I have copied your WordPress htaccess example and posted with and without `action="test/submit"` and it still doesn't post the vars.

Comment: edited again, adding an exact working example, based on your pasted files

Comment: +1. If that exact code works then you're right, it must be a permission (or server?) issue. I have updated my question with a work-around I'm using for the time being.

Comment: As a test, I set every file/folder to 777 and it still didn't work.

Comment: It's possibly an Apache 2.4 issue. I needed to add `parse_str(file_get_contents("php://input"),$_POST);` to index.php.